# Simplify $\sum_{k=0}^a\binom ak\prod_{j=0}^{a-1}(b-k-j)$, the number of injections from $A$ to $B$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

The number of injections from the set $A$ to the set $B$ is $\prod_{k=0}^{a-1}(b-k)$, typically denoted by  [the Pochammer symbol $(b)_a$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials), where $a=|A|$ and $b=|B|$.

I'm interested in determining the same number, but for injections that are "[partial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function)", i.e., functions where not all members of $A$ are assigned an output. In other words, $f(x)$ does not exist for all $x\in A$, but when it does, we still have that $f(x)=f(y)\implies x=y$.

Suppose that precisely $k$ out of the members of $A$ get no output, these can be chosen in $\binom ak$ ways. The remaining $a-k$ all get an output, so there are $(b)_{a-k}$ injections in this case. Summing over $k$ gives the answer,
$$\sum_{k=0}^a\binom ak(b)_{a-k}.$$
I'm wondering if it's possible to simplify this quantity in some way.

Comment: @lulu Apologies, I swapped two of the letters around. It should work now.

Comment: For what it's worth, I put `Sum[Binomial[a, k] Product[b - i, {i, 0, k - 1}], {k, 0, a}]` into Mathematica and got `(-1)^a HypergeometricU[-a, 1 - a + b, -1]`. It's too bad you can't see from this expression that it's symmetric in $a$ and $b$ (but you can see it in a table of values).

Comment: One thing that might be helpful is that your sum can be written as $\sum_k \binom a k \binom b k k!$, since partial injective functions correspond to choosing subsets from two sets of the same size and a bijection from one to the other.